# Влияет ли местоположение вводного слова на смысл предложения?

Tags: грамотная-речь, вводные-слова

Есть ли какие-либо тонкие смысловые отличия между предложениями "Вероятно, я не смогу сегодня прийти" и "Я, вероятно, не смогу сегодня прийти"? Или оба варианта полностью равноправны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что говорится в справочнике по правописанию и стилистике, Д.Э. Розенталь.

Не являясь членами предложения, вводные слова свободно располагаются в нем, если относятся к предложению в целом; **ср.:Казалось, он уснул. – Он, казалось, уснул. – Он уснул, казалось.**

Вместе с тем следует отметить, что смысловая нагрузка вводного слова в приведенных вариантах неодинакова: **в большей степени она отмечается в** **первом из них, где в начале предложения слово казалось по значению приближается к простому предложению в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения; последние два варианта равноценны.**

Answer (score 2):

Изменение структуры предложения обычно всегда связано с выражением разных смысловых оттенков.

(1) Вероятно, //я не смогу сегодня прийти"

(2) Я, вероятно, //не смогу сегодня прийти.

Как мне кажется, в предложении (1) вводное слово выделяется паузой, поэтому оно **более значимо**.

В предложении (2) местоимение и вводное слово составляют первую часть предложения (раздельно, с паузой, их трудно произнести), поэтому вводное слово интонационно не выделяется (в данном случае действует грамматический принцип постановки запятых).